# Есть ли в PL/SQL эквивалент T-SQL сет ориентированной конкатенации переменной?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, переменные

В *Microsoft SQL Server* (T-SQL) существует лаконичный, элегантный и высокопроизводительный способ заполнения переменной с типом `VARCHAR` конкатенцией значений одной колонки из нескольких строк в таблице, например:

```sql
DECLARE @vals NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @vals = ISNULL(@vals + ',', '')
+ <some_varchar_column>
FROM <some_table>
```

Переменная `@vals` заполнится строкой с запятой как разделитель из всех значений в `some_column` всех записей `some_table`, например: `value1,value2,value3, ...`.

Как сделать что-то подобное в PL/SQL таким же элегантным способом (без необходимости писать цикл или курсор)?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [PL/SQL equivalent of T-SQL set-oriented variable concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63712357) от участника [Cade Bryant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7016967/cade-bryant)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63712357

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```
select listagg(dname, ',') within group (order by dname) result
from dept;
    
RESULT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNTING,OPERATIONS,RESEARCH,SALES
```

---

На [dbfiddle с тестовой таблицей](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a5a56e1900e39f52f07f5886b77a37ee).

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63712376) от участника [@Littlefoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9097906/littlefoot)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Нет, прямого эквивалента в PL/SQL нет. Есть SQL функция [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466), которая возвращает аналогичный результат.

Но иногда всё же имеет смысл сделать свою собственную функцию. Это довольно просто:

```
select * from vals
/
        ID VAL                                          
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 value1                                       
         1 value2                                       
         2 value3                                       
         2 value4                                       
         2 value5                                       
         3 value6     

create or replace type listofvals is table of varchar2 (64)
/
with function join (vals listofvals, delimiter char := ',') return varchar2 is
    ret varchar2 (32767);
begin 
    for i in 1..vals.count loop 
        ret := ret||vals(i)||delimiter; end loop;
    return rtrim (ret, delimiter);
end; 
select id, join (cast (collect (val order by val) as listofvals), ' -> ') res
from vals
group by id
/
```

Результат:

```
        ID RES                             
---------- --------------------------------
         1 value1 -> value2                
         2 value3 -> value4 -> value5      
         3 value6
```

---

PS В версии 20c ожидается новый тип - итератор, который позволит записать `for-loop` более лаконично.